# Can I automate oracle 11g installation on Windows?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am looking to automate my appplication installation on standalone machines, so wondering if I can automate the oracle 11g setup as well? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [Help-Center/asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). To get help you should do a bit more than you expect from others, firstly show the effort you put in your question.

Comment: You can use a response file to do a silent install since at least some time in the 8i days.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b15660/app_nonint.htm  If you are just looking to install the Oracle client, though, you may really want to look to see whether you can ship the Instant Client with your application so that you don't need to use the Oracle Universal Installer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of installing Oracle on Windows use [VM with pre installed software](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html). [Here](http://praitheesh.blogspot.com/2013/10/oracle-developer-day-vm-how-to-use-pre.html) you have some instructions how to use it.

Generally I don't think automated instalation for database make sense. You can configure database somwhere in the net and your application can use remote databse (just create a schema for each user). Also database server has usually different requirements so it is not popular to install DB at same machine as application.

Comment: Thank you for your response, you are right about installing DB on different machine and connecting my application to that machine. But this is more like a standalone setup, so am experimenting on the automation procedure. So just wondered if I can automate oracle as well. If its not possible, I can definitely follow what you suggested and automate just my application.